# Is a request to memory/RAM considered an I/O request like a request to disk?

Tags: c#

An I/O request is a request to the disk and a request to/via the network. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Is a request to the memory/RAM also an I/O request?

Comment: Do you have a code example? I am not 100% sure what you mean with "request to the memory/RAM".

Comment: While it's true that the values of RAM also are fetched from outside the CPU, it is normally not considered an I/O request. Usually I/O requests are initiated and the CPU goes and does something else. When the request completes, a CPU interrupt is generated to tell the CPU that it's done.

Comment: The answer is no

Comment: I can be, accessing memory can cause a paging fault and that may require I/O to access the paging file.   But it is never something that you consider when reasoning about the way a program behaves.  Always mention why you ask a question.

Comment: @HansKilian why is it not considered to be an I/O request? Because it's so fast? Or because it's so close to the CPU?

Comment: Because getting data from memory is synchronous. I/O requests are asynchronous - i.e. the CPU goes and does something else while the request completes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take `MemoryStream` vs `FileStream` as an example, check the following from Microsoft documentation:

> The MemoryStream class creates streams that have memory as a backing store instead of a disk or a network connection. MemoryStream encapsulates data stored as an unsigned byte array that is initialized upon creation of a MemoryStream object, or the array can be created as empty. The encapsulated data is directly accessible in memory. Memory streams can reduce the need for temporary buffers and files in an application.

So data are accessed directly from the memory without an I/O request.
In case you use `FileStream` you will access the disk directly so an I/O request is needed.

Now general speaking the memory is not considered an I/O, you can build a computer with only CPU and memory since they are the most important part, but the I/O (which the disk is considered part of this category) is secondary part, computers have two types of memory the main memory for the RAM, and secondary memory for other I/O storage type like disk for example, which differs in the way the CPU process their requests.

Comment: OP appears to be talking about _"RAM"_ and not say memory stream sadly